# How Nodejs with Restify Handle Concurrent Request?

Tags: node.js, restify

With the following code:

```
var counter = 0;
server.get(
    '/test,
    function(request, response, next)
    {
        console.log('Counter', ++counter);
        next();
    }
);
```

How does the counter variable is affected with several concurrent connections?  Restify (or Node) has some kind of connection insolation or a queue of incoming requests?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Node (in the normal case) runs your application on only one single thread, so there are no concurrency issues within a single callback.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That should be made into an answer.

Comment: @HeadCode Not being a node guru I was hoping for someone else to make a more complete answer so that I didn't some nitty gritty detail wrong where I didn't know there was one :) Didn't see it stayed unanswered, so I'll try to write something up when I get a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, `restify` is wrapping one of a few different packages: `spdy`, `http`, or `https`.

```
if (options.spdy) {
    this.spdy = true;
    this.server = spdy.createServer(options.spdy);
} else if ((options.cert || options.certificate) && options.key) {
    this.ca = options.ca;
    this.certificate = options.certificate || options.cert;
    this.key = options.key;
    this.passphrase = options.passphrase || null;
    this.secure = true;

    this.server = https.createServer({
        ca: self.ca,
        cert: self.certificate,
        key: self.key,
        passphrase: self.passphrase,
        rejectUnauthorized: options.rejectUnauthorized,
        requestCert: options.requestCert,
        ciphers: options.ciphers
    });
} else if (options.httpsServerOptions) {
    this.server = https.createServer(options.httpsServerOptions);
} else {
    this.server = http.createServer();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/5.x/lib/server.js

Those packages manage the asynchronous nature of requests, which are handled as Events within `restify`.  [The EventListener calls all listeners synchronously in the order in which they were registered.](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous).  In this case, `restify` is the listener and will process the requests in the order they are received.

**Scaling**

That being said, web servers like `restify` are often scaled up by releasing them on multiple processes behind a proxy like `nginx`.  In this case, `nginx` would be splitting the incoming requests between the processes effectively allowing the web server to handle a larger concurrent load.

**Node.js Limitations**

Lastly, just keep in mind this is all limited by the behavior of Node.js.  Since the app runs on a single thread, you can effectively block all requests while performing a slow synchronous request.

```
server.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFileSync('something.txt', ...) // blocks the other requests until done
});
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong: Nodejs uses a connection queue per server instance. It's single threaded, but escalable because multiple instances can run the same app, in the same or another machine, balancing the load dynamically (if you use the cluster module or something like that).

I'm i right?

Comment: Node.js doesn't use a connection queue per server instance.  It would be per app instance.  Typically, something like `nginx` would be used for scaling.  It does look like the `cluster` module is stable now though: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html.  At a glance, it appears it is limited to a scaling on a single server.